# Spark SQL Timeout

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to run a relatively simple Spark SQL command on a Spark standalone cluster

```
select a.name, b.name, s.score
from score s
inner join A a on a.id = s.a_id
inner join B b on b.id = s.b_id
where pmod(a.id, 3) != 3 and pmod(b.id, 3) != 0
```

The table sizes are as follows

```
A: 25,000
B: 2,500,000
score: 25,000,000
```

Therefore, from this I would expect the get a result of 25,000,000 rows.  I want to run this query with Spark SQL and then process each line.  Here is the relevant spark code

```
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
val sql = "<above SQL>"
sqlContext.sql(sql).first
```

This command runs fine when the size of table score is 200,000, but doesn't run now.  Here are the relevant logs

```
14/12/04 16:35:14 WARN LazyStruct: Extra bytes detected at the end of the row! Ignoring similar problems.
14/12/04 16:35:43 WARN LazyStruct: Extra bytes detected at the end of the row! Ignoring similar problems.
14/12/04 16:36:24 WARN LazyStruct: Extra bytes detected at the end of the row! Ignoring similar problems.
14/12/04 16:37:11 WARN LazyStruct: Extra bytes detected at the end of the row! Ignoring similar problems.
14/12/04 16:38:13 WARN LazyStruct: Extra bytes detected at the end of the row! Ignoring similar problems.
14/12/04 16:39:19 WARN LazyStruct: Extra bytes detected at the end of the row! Ignoring similar problems.
14/12/04 16:39:48 WARN LazyStruct: Extra bytes detected at the end of the row! Ignoring similar problems.
14/12/04 16:40:08 WARN MemoryStore: Not enough space to store block broadcast_12 in memory! Free memory is 1938057068 bytes.
14/12/04 16:40:08 WARN MemoryStore: Persisting block broadcast_12 to disk instead.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [5 minutes]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BroadcastHashJoin.execute(joins.scala:431)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project.execute(basicOperators.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Limit.executeCollect(basicOperators.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD.collect(SchemaRDD.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD.take(SchemaRDD.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD.take(SchemaRDD.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1092)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:20)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:25)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:27)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:29)
    at <init>(<console>:31)
    at .<init>(<console>:35)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:789)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1062)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:615)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:646)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:610)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:859)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:616)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:624)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loop(SparkILoop.scala:629)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:954)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:997)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

My initial thought was to increase this timeout, but this doesn't look possible without recompiling the source as show [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/joins/BroadcastHashJoin.scala).  In the parent directory I also see a few different joins, but I'm not sure how to get spark to use those other types of joins.

I was also trying to fix my first warning about persisting to disk by increasing spark.executor.memory up to 10g, but that didn't solve the problem.

Does anyone know how I can actually run this query?

Comment: Seeing similar problems - did you ever find a solution for this one?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are running into the timeout of the broadcast join. For some reason it is an undocumented configuration option called `spark.sql.broadcastTimeout` (by default 300s).

So you could try to increase this (worked for us), or make Spark not do a broadcast join (even though it is the suggested thing for joining a small table to a large one, see https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/latest/databricks_guide/06%20Spark%20SQL%20%26%20DataFrames/05%20BroadcastHashJoin%20-%20scala.html).